# Are almost all rooted trees asymmetric?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

It's well known that almost all graphs are asymmetric (have trivial automorphism group) and that almost all free trees are symmetric.

By which argument do I see whether almost all *rooted* trees are asymmetric or symmetric?

Comment: Did you try adapting the argument for unrooted trees, e.g. as given in  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_graph#Trees?